# How to get bunched result

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem regarding display results from a mysql table. I have a table like this in my MySql Database.

Table name - books

```
+----+--------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
| id |           name           | author | price | pages |     topic      |
+----+--------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
|  1 | HTML for beginners       | Sanju  |   200 |   400 | HTML           |
|  2 | Master in JavaScript     | Sanju  |   300 |   500 | JavaScript     |
|  3 | Object Oriented PHP      | Henry  |   200 |   500 | php            |
|  4 | Advance AngularJS        | Henry  |   100 |   400 | AngularJs      |
|  5 | Basic Computer Operation | Fred   |   200 |   300 | Basic Computer |
|  6 | Rock the world with CSS  | Henry  |   400 |   500 | Css            |
|  7 | Be perfect in browsers   | Mark   |   250 |   300 | browser        |
+----+--------------------------+--------+-------+-------+----------------+
```

I would like to display as below.

```
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|     Author Name     |     Henry     |       |           | 
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+-------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|        Book name        |         Price | pages |   topic   |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| Object Oriented PHP     |           200 |   500 | php       |
| Advance AngularJS       |           100 |   400 | AngularJs |
| Rock the world with CSS |           400 |   500 | Css       |
+-------------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|     Author Name     |     Sanju     |       |           | 
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+----------------------+-------+-------+------------+
|      Book name       | Price | pages |   topic    |
+----------------------+-------+-------+------------+
| HTML for beginners   |   200 |   400 | HTML       |
| Master in JavaScript |   300 |   500 | JavaScript |
+----------------------+-------+-------+------------+
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|     Author Name     |     Fred      |       |           | 
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+--------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
|        Book name         | Price | pages |     topic      |
+--------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
| Basic Computer Operation |   200 |   300 | Basic Computer |
+--------------------------+-------+-------+----------------+
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
|     Author Name     |     Mark      |       |           | 
+---------------------+---------------+-------+-----------+
+------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
|       Book name        | Price | pages |  topic  |
+------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
| Be perfect in browsers |   250 |   300 | browser |
+------------------------+-------+-------+---------+
```

I need both php and mysql code. Thanks

Comment: SO is not code generation engine. Please provide what you have tried so far to get to the result and specify where do you face difficulties.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears that the question is "write my code for me" rather than "help me understand why my code isn't working".

Comment: Free code though you tried nothing? Hell no .

Comment: @RagingBull Thanks for your reply. Actually I would like to know **How do you solve this sort of problem ??**. How do you write your sql and how do you write your php code to display the result ?? I searched a lot through Google but could not find any good result. Thanks

Comment: @abuabu: If you ask for how do I solve this kind of problem, then I guess this question will be closed saying "opinion based". However, your question is on the way to be closed. You should fetch the data using `ORDER BY` then make the required changes from php. Look at your question from a third person's view. It looks like asking for complete code. No offense!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you simply need to order your data by author, however there is no ordering that puts them in this order:

- Henry
- Sanju
- Fred
- Mark

Because this is neither alphabetical ascending or descending?

The following queries will enable you to order by author ASC/DESC:

```
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY author ASC;
SELECT * FROM books ORDER BY author DESC;
```

However if you need to output in this strange order, you'll likely need to retrieve each author's books individually and output them one by one:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = 'Henry';
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = 'Sanju';
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = 'Fred';
SELECT * FROM books WHERE author = 'Mark';
```

I wont however be posting how to retrieve the data from the database, for that you can read online tutorials for PHP/MySQL code help. See the below link for a friendly PDO reference:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Hope this helps - sorry I can't be of any more help.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks @Dan Belden for your reply. I think its not ORDER BY issue. I would like to fetch **Grouped** result, Like which books are written by **Henry**, which books belong to **Sanju** . Thanks

Comment: I used group_concat() in this regard. Thanks